# Raspberry Pi's apt-get cannot find repositories

Tags: raspbian, apt

After entering: `apt-get install python3-pip` on bash for my Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B) I get [this output (linky)](http://pastebin.com/Swnit5Z0).

I've tried the usual dance of `apt-get install -f`, `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to no avail. My device can access the outside world (ie - can ping google.com).

It's a freshly installed Raspbian image downloaded from the website, and all that I have done since getting it configured is to create a new user.

Any suggestions on how to proceed from here?

**EDIT:**
`wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1-dev_2.1.‌​0-1+deb7u1_armhf.deb` yields:

```
--2015-06-10 14:08:43--  http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1-dev_2.1.%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B0-1+deb7u1_armhf.deb
Resolving mirrordirector.raspbian.org (mirrordirector.raspbian.org)... 5.153.225.207, 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11
Connecting to mirrordirector.raspbian.org (mirrordirector.raspbian.org)|5.153.225.207|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-06-10 14:08:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2015-06-10 14:08:43--  http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1-dev_2.1.%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B0-1+deb7u1_armhf.deb
Reusing existing connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-06-10 14:08:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: What happens if you try `wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1-dev_2.1.0-1+deb7u1_armhf.deb`, or point a browser to http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/expat?

Comment: updated question. Reckon it's a DNS problem?

Comment: No, wget says "unable to resolve host address" in that case.  If you're working on another computer in the same location, you could try navigating to `http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/` (it is WWW browsable) to see if that works.

Comment: Yeah - I tried it on my desktop (same network) and it resolves fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, I couldn't resolve the default mirror's repositories. I added the University of Oxford's mirror [(list of all Raspbian mirrors)](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors) to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

For the folks who may follow, my `sources.list` file now looks as follows:

```
# Original mirror
#deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi

# Oxford University mirror
deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free rpi


# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: I had this, the weekend I got my first RPi, and I thought (I had a) "broken RPi"!  Turns out that the mirrordirector.raspbian.org is a URL that gets resolved into a URL for a mirror that is deemed "most suitable" for the particular caller.  However if that system is not working for any reason then you get "404" errors and no packages - even if there ARE mirrors up and ready to supply all you want in the way of RPi packages.  Having a known good mirror for *your own geo-location* as a standby in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or in a file in `./sources.list.d/` sub-dir) is a good fall-back!

Comment: This example is for `wheezy` I was able to successfully use it to download `jessie` by replacing each instance of `wheezy` with `jessie`. Thanks for the helpful example.